# Django templates "include" tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm trying to lessen the repetition of appending the same div. I am using ajax and I want to pass a context to another file after every successful posts but it always results to TemplateSyntaxError.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /items/order/2546
Could not parse the remainder: '${data}' from '${data}'
```

Is it possible to do something like this in jQuery or am I just doing it wrong?

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'namespace:name' %}",
    headers: {
       'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
    data: {
       item: "123"
    },
    method: "POST",
    success: (response) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response);
        $('#container').append(`{% include "partials/repeating_item.html" with response=${data} %}`);
    }
});
```

`partials/repeating_item.html` shows something like this

```html
<div class="list-item item-{{ response.order_id }}">
    <a href="#" class="item-name" data-item='{{ response.item_id }}'>
        <div class="svg-div">
            <!-- some svg -->
            <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="item-summary-title">
        {{ response.item_name }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="item-price-div">
        <div><span>${{ response.item_price }}</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the ajax response returns an object

```js
{
    item_id: 69,
    order_id: 2546,
    item_name: "X Gaming Chair",
    item_price: "399.00"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the full error

Comment: yes you can do that in jquery . show what you have inside `response` and also `partials/repeating_item.html` htmls .

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply. I edited my question and added the error, response and html contents.

Comment: it is json array or only one object is return ?

Comment: Only one. I'm returning a dictionary from the backend view

Answer (score 0):

You can create that `html` inside your success function of ajax can append same to your `container` div

***Demo Code*** :

```js
let data = {
  item_id: 69,
  order_id: 2546,
  item_name: "X Gaming Chair",
  item_price: "399.00"
}
//ajax codes here ..
/*$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'namespace:name' %}",
    headers: {
       'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
    data: {
       item: "123"
    },
    method: "POST",
    success: (response) => {*/
    //create that html here ..and add json datas 
// let data = JSON.parse(response);
$('#container').append(`<div class="list-item item-${data.order_id }">
    <a href="#" class="item-name" data-item='${data.item_id}'>
      <div class="svg-div">
        <!-- some svg -->
        <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="item-summary-title">
      ${data.item_name}
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="item-price-div">
        <div><span>${data.item_price}</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`);

/*}
})*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```